# Cannot connect to working ssh server

Tags: xubuntu, ssh, fedora

I connected to my vps server via ssh on the Fedora 25 desktop. Although, when I try to connect via Xubuntu 16.04 laptop (using even the same router) I have `connection timed out` error.

What can be the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: are you using dns name of the server or ip?

Comment: @hamiheim , I use noip.com which directs to server's static ipv4, but i tried to connect directly to ip and it still is not working only from laptop

Comment: using RSA/DSA or PSK for authentication?

Comment: Wifi for laptop is WPA2-PSK, desktop connected via ethernet

Comment: sorry I should have specified, are you connecting with SSH using RSA/DSA keys or with username and password?

Comment: with username and password. Actually, I have root and git account - connect to root via password, git - via rsa key, and both are dropped by timeout

Comment: well unless you specifically enabled it, you shouldn't be able to login via root.

Comment: So on that note, I would say you probably have either an RSA key mismatch, or you didn't authorize the public key (depending on how your generated it)

Comment: I just have both logins (to git and to root) dropped on laptop and connecting on desktop. So I just cannot even login root with password

Comment: Okay well quick test to make sure you're at least reaching the server. Initiate the SSH request using a different (incorrect) port. For example: `ssh -p 1234 user@remotehost`. If you get a response saying the connection was refused then at least we know you're hitting it.

Comment: yep, it is refused

Comment: Have you already tried rebooting/restarting the SSH service then? That's about the only thing left I can think of.

Comment: Of course, as I saw lemrm's answer. But after poweroff and some magic beyond human's mind laptop could connect. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem years ago. There I had a cloned server VM on an ESXi, I could not reach and I tried a lot i.E. reinstall ssh, build new certificates, change server names and cleaned knowing hosts. In the end a reboot of this ESXi solved my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, reboot is not remedy for me as it is a problem of laptop (Fedora connects without any problem)

Comment: So have you already tried rebooting/restarting the SSH service then?

Comment: `Of course, as I saw lemrm's answer. But after poweroff and some magic beyond human's mind laptop could connect. Thanks for help :)` ... If you think this was a helpful answer, you could accept it!